# Create static array from excel/CSV values

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a large array in Excel containing different data types. See snippet below:

```
Param,String1,String2,Bits,Disp fmt,Extra,use act
0,Coarse,Tune,4,2,,0
1,Wave,form,4,7,128,0
2,Filter,Type,4,8,,0
3,F Env,A,4,5,3,0
4,F Env,D/R,4,5,3,0
5,F Env,S,4,5,3,0
6,A Env,A,4,6,6,0
7,A Env,D,4,6,6,0
8,A Env,S,4,6,6,0
9,A Env,R,4,6,6,0
10,LFO,Wave,4,7,64,0
```

....... etc

There's 2 strings and some integers.  I need to work out a way to get this into C++ as efficiently as possible. It is for an embedded system, so needs to be totally self-contained within the C++ code (can't open other apps, read files etc).

My initial thought is to create a class containing the datatypes in the columns.
Then declare a static array of the class. But how do I then populate the array at run-time with the data?

It's essential that the array is declared as static const, so that it goes into program memory, not SRAM.

With regard to the string elements, only some of the rows in the data will have strings, so keen not to initialize a fixed size array for them, when only some will be filled.

Obviously this data doesn't have to initially exist in Excel, if there's better ways of generating large static arrays in C++, I'd be happy to try.

Comment: Do you know how big this file is?  You can't have an array where you don't know how big it is going to be.

Comment: So you want to hard-code the data into your program? Then I suggest making a small "pre-processor" program which reads the input file, and creates a C++ source file that initializes an array of structures with the data. Then build with the generated source file. And since you make your program parsing the input file to run on the *host* system, it can use any nice and good CSV parsing library it damn well pleases. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, 128 rows, each with 2 strings (max 12 chars) and 5 ints

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK, parsing CSV to generate C++ code is fine.  Can do that.  But what is the actual syntax to populate a static array at compile-time?

Comment: `someStructureType myArrayOfStructures[] = { { /* data for first structure */ }, { /* data for second structure */ }, ... }`

Comment: @paulsoulsby: If you have to ask this question, you are in urgent need of an introductory book about C++. Static initilsation is a basic construct of the language.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's perfect thanks.  Didn't realise it was that simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comment, parse the CSV using external program.
Then create array of struct. This [thread](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13545/using-progmem-to-store-array-of-structs) shows syntax options.

Specifically in this case, I created the following struct:

```
typedef struct ParamInfo
{
    const char *label1;
    const char *label2;
    uint8_t bits;
    uint8_t dispFmt;
    uint8_t tag;
    uint8_t ctrl;
} ParamInfo;
```

Then wrote a parser that created a  look-up of all the different phrases used and created static consts of all the phrases, so each was only stored once in memory.  This uses the minimum possible memory, as opposed to declaring an array in the struct of the max desired size and declaring the same phrase multiple times.

```
static const char S_COARSE[] = "Coarse";
static const char S_TUNE[] = "Tune";
static const char S_WAVE[] = "Wave";
static const char S_FORM[] = "form";
static const char S_FILTER[] = "Filter";
```

etc...

Then populated a static const array of the struct:

```
static const ParamInfo ATM_PARAM_INFO[48] = {
    {
        S_COARSE,S_TUNE,4,2,0,1 // ATM_COARSETUNE
    },
    {
        S_WAVE,S_FORM,4,7,128,2 // ATM_WAVEFORM
    },
    {
        S_FILTER,S_TYPE,4,8,0,3 // ATM_FILTTYPE
    },
    {
        S_F_ENV,S_A,4,5,3,4 // ATM_FENVA
```

etc....